# How can I insert data in table form into another table provided some specific conditions are satisfied

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Logic: If today is Monday (reference 'time' table), data present in S should be inserted into M (along with a sent_day column which will have today's date).

If today is not Monday, dates corresponding to current week (unique week_id) should be checked in M table. If any of these dates are available in M then S should not be inserted into M. If these dates are not available in M then S should be inserted into M

```
time 
+------------+------------+----------------+
|   cal_dt   |    cal_day |        week_id |
+------------+------------+----------------+
| 2020-03-23 |  Monday    |            123 |
| 2020-03-24 |    Tuesday |            123 |
| 2020-03-25 | Wednesday  |            123 |
| 2020-03-26 | Thursday   |            123 |
| 2020-03-27 | Friday     |            123 |
| 2020-03-30 | Monday     |            124 |
| 2020-03-31 | Tueday     |            124 |
+------------+------------+----------------+
```

M

```
+------------+----------+-------+
|  sent_day  |   item   | price |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 2020-03-11 | pen      |    10 |
| 2020-03-11 | book     |    50 |
| 2020-03-13 | Eraser   |     5 |
| 2020-03-13 | sharpner |     5 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

S

```
+----------+-------+
|   item   | price |
+----------+-------+
| pen      |    25 |
| book     |    20 |
| Eraser   |    10 |
| sharpner |     3 |
+----------+-------+
```

```
Insert INTO M  
SELECT 
CASE WHEN(SELECT cal_day FROM time WHERE cal_dt = current_date) = 'Monday' THEN  s.*
     ELSE  
     (CASE WHEN(SELECT cal_dt FROM time WHERE wk_id =(SELECT wk_id FROM time WHERE cal_dt = current_date ) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sent_day FROM M) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
     THEN  s.* ELSE END
     FROM s
```

Comment: A CASE expression in SQL can only return a single (scalar) value, so `then s.*` is invalid in any SQL dialect.

Comment: is any alternative to case expression which will return table ??

Comment: Provide table schema for both the tables.

Comment: i am using Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two separate INSERT  statements:

The first condition ("if today is monday") is quite easy:

```
insert into m (sent_day, item, price)
select current_date, item, price
from s
where exists (select *
              from "time"
              where cal_dt = current_date 
                and cal_day = 'Monday');
```

I find storing the date **and** the week day a bit confusing as the week day can easily be extracted from the day. For the test "if today is Monday" it's actually not necessary to consult the  "time" table at all:

```
insert into m (sent_day, item, price)
select current_date, item, price
from s
where extract(dow from current_date) = 1;
```

The second part is a bit more complicated, but if I understand it correctly, it should be something like this:

```
insert into m (sent_day, item, price)
select current_date, item, price
from s
where not exists (select *
                  from m 
                  where m.sent_day in (select cal_dt 
                                       from "time" t
                                       where cal_dt = current_date 
                                         and cal_day <> 'Monday'));
```

If you just want a single INSERT statement, you could simply do a UNION ALL between the two selects:

```
insert into m (sent_day, item, price)
select current_date, item, price
from s
where extract(dow from current_date) = 1
union all
select current_date, item, price
from s
where not exists (select *
                  from m 
                  where m.sent_day in (select cal_dt 
                                       from "time" t
                                       where cal_dt = current_date 
                                         and cal_day <> 'Monday'));
```